# How do I track down the source of a ssh login message?

Tags: scripting, login, bashrc, profile, mail-command

I installed mailutils on my linux machine with Linux Mint 15 (basically Ubuntu 13.04).

When I log in, I get the following:

```
Welcome to Linux Mint 15 Olivia (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-32-generic i686)

Welcome to Linux Mint
 * Documentation:  http://www.linuxmint.com
No mail.
Last login: Wed Nov  6 01:33:10 2013 from xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BFL SingleSC: 3s ago - [2013-11-06 01:37:33] 5s:57.83 avg:57.96 u:56.96 Gh/s
```

I have added the last line, colorized as I prefer, as a custom script that updates me on the status of my BFL bitcoin hashing rig in ~/.bashrc.

I now want to color the rest of it, especially the `No mail.` line, from mailutils, and remove the duplicated 'Welcome to Linux Mint' messages and newline.

I've been searching for the mailutils section specifically, and can't find any reference to it in:

- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.profile
- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/*
- /etc/bashrc
- /etc/init.d/*
- /etc/rc.local
- /etc/rc*.d (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, S)

So - how do I go about finding where these messages are generated so I can modify and color them as I like?

Comment: That message is coming from `pam`.

Comment: How do I colorize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Updated answer based on some researching

### Remove duplicated welcome messages

- Since you login with ssh, the first welcome message should be coming from `/etc/issue.net`. To remove the message, just remove the contents of that file.
- To remove the second welcome message, remove the contents of `/etc/motd`.

### Colorize the line about mail

To colorize that line, the easiest option I can think of requires quite a bit of low-level work: the option is that you modify and build `pam_mail.so` yourself.

#### These are the steps for modifying it and installing the modified version

1. Download [Linux-PAM source from linux-pam.org (the official project site)](http://www.linux-pam.org/library/Linux-PAM-1.1.8.tar.gz).
2. Extract the source (this will create a new directory named `Linux-PAM-1.1.8`) and cd to it:

   ```
   # tar xzvf Linux-PAM-1.1.8.tar.gz
   # cd Linux-PAM-1.1.8
   ```
3. Change the following lines (the lines which begins with `+`, 4 lines at all) in file `modules/pam_mail/pam_mail.c` to be as the following diff shows (produced with `diff -u`)(the filename `pam_mail.c.new` is just my temporary file that I could produce that diff):

   ```
   --- pam_mail.c  2013-06-18 17:11:21.000000000 +0300
   +++ pam_mail.c.new      2013-12-29 16:57:49.759298926 +0200
   @@ -294,17 +294,17 @@
             switch (type)
               {
               case HAVE_NO_MAIL:
   -             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("No mail."));
   +             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("\\033[0;1;31mNo mail.\\033[0m"));
                 break;
               case HAVE_NEW_MAIL:
   -             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("You have new mail."));
   +             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("\\033[0;1;31mYou have new mail.\\033[0m"));
                 break;
               case HAVE_OLD_MAIL:
   -             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("You have old mail."));
   +             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("\\033[0;1;31mYou have old mail.\\033[0m"));
                 break;
               case HAVE_MAIL:
               default:
   -             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("You have mail."));
   +             retval = pam_info (pamh, "%s", _("\\033[0;1;31mYou have mail.\\033[0m"));
                 break;
               }
           else
   ```

   I have simply added `\\033[0;1;31m` to the beginning of those messages and `\\033[0m` to the end of those messages.

   **Note:** Now it displays those messages as red; from [ascii-table.com page about Ansi Escape Sequences under title Set Graphics Mode](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) you can find more complete list about colors and other tricks about customising terminal output.
4. Compile it (**Note:** from here to the end I assume that your working directory is `Linux-PAM-1.1.8`, the very same directory to which we cd'd at the beginning, i.e. the "root" directory of the Linux-PAM package):

   ```
   # ./configure
   # make
   ```
5. Backup your existing `pam_mail.so` in case that the new one breaks your system (I doubt it will break, but it's always good to have the original file in safe):

   ```
   # cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/pam_mail.so ~/
   ```
6. Copy the file `modules/pam_mail/.libs/pam_mail.so` to `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/`:

   ```
   # cp modules/pam_mail/.libs/pam_mail.so /lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/
   ```
7. Log out and again in (or start a new ssh session, whatever), and you should see red "No mail." message (assuming you have no new mail).

## The old, obsolete answer

The mail message can be disabled by changing the following line in file `/etc/pam.d/system-login` from

```
session optional pam_mail.so dir=/var/spool/mail standard
```

to

```
session optional pam_mail.so dir=/var/spool/mail nopen
```

[Reference from archlinux's forums.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145013)

The text before the mail information is in `/etc/motd`, and you can disable it to be printed when login with ssh by putting the following line to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
PrintMotd no
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm tracing down some of this. I don't have a `system-login` file, but I do have `/etc/pam.d/login` file that has a call to `pam_mail.so`, which I have traced to `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/security`. What I really want to do is just inject colors before and after the output, so that messages like `No Mail` are in a different color.

Comment: I have tried `echo -e "\e[36m"` in `/etc/pam.d/login`, with no luck. I can color the entire thing by editing files in `/etc/update-motd.d/` however this colors the mail prompt and the last login time, and I can't seem to isolate the mail part. I feel like I'm getting close - any ideas?

Comment: I think too that you are getting close, but I don't have any ideas now. I'll take a deeper look at it when I have some time.